# Dynamically change Leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox, gpx

First, to get some context, I asked [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201432/load-multiple-gpx-files-to-leaflet-map) a few weeks ago.

I now have Leaflet parsing a folder of `gpx` files, and drawing all of them in one map instance, using the Omnivore plugin.

Now what I need is for those files to change dynamically. I have a slider that represents a time interval. Each time I use the slider, I narrow the interval in which I want the tracks to be shown.

Ex: My slider goes from 15th of January to the 15th of May. So, the map shows all tracks from that time. If I change the slider to show from the 1st of April to the 15th of May, the map should react accordingly and re-draw the corresponding files, erasing from the map the tracks from before the 1st of April.

The problem is that I can't seem to get it doing this, since I keep getting a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined

When I make a `console.log` of the layer, in the line where the problem happens, it prints at exactly the same time, the layer and then an `undefined`. I don't know why this happens and it is very hard do debug.

My code is as follows:

```
setTimeout(function() {

          var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
          osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attributionControl: false});
          var ggl = new L.Google();

          angular.element($elem[0]).append(angular.element('<div id="trackmap'+ trackmapCount +'" style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 25px); border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>'));
          trackmaps[trackmapCount] = new L.Map('trackmap'+ trackmapCount +'', {center: new L.LatLng(center[0], center[1]), zoom: 10});
          trackmaps[trackmapCount].addControl(new L.Control.Layers( {'Google':ggl,'OSM':osm}, {}));
          console.log('map'+ trackmapCount +'');
          var layer1 = osm.addTo(trackmaps[trackmapCount]);
          createTracks(jsonRes);

          $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $elem[0].parentNode.clientWidth;
          }, function ( w ) {
            if ( !w ) { return; }
            for(var i = 0; i < trackmapCount; i++) {
              trackmaps[i].invalidateSize();
            }
          });

          $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $elem[0].parentNode.clientHeight;
          }, function ( h ) {
            if ( !h ) { return; }
            for(var i = 0; i < trackmapCount; i++) {
              trackmaps[i].invalidateSize();
            }
          });

          $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            rootScopeBroadcast();
          });

          var rootScopeBroadcast = $rootScope.$on('rootScope:broadcast-timeline_slider', function (event, data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < trackmapCount; i++) {
              trackmaps[i].removeLayer(runLayer);
            }
              var new_tracks = sliderProcessing(data.min_time, data.max_time, jsonRes)
              createTracks(new_tracks); // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
          });


          function createTracks (track_list) {


              myStyle = {
                  "color": "#0033ff",
                  "weight": 5,
                  "opacity": 0.65,
                  "clickable": true
              };

              customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
                  style: myStyle,
              });


              for (var i = 0; i < track_list.length; i += 1) {
                runLayer = omnivore.gpx(folderPath + track_list[i], null, customLayer) 
                  .on('ready', function() {
                      //runLayer.showExtremities('arrowM');
                  })
                  .addTo(trackmaps[trackmapCount])
//a console.log of trackmaps[trackmapCount] here shows both the layer and an undefined at the same time
                  .on('click', function(d) {
                      console.log(d);
                  });
              }

          }

          trackmapCount++;
          delay = 0;

          }, delay);
```

I'm probably missing some Leaflet re-draw function, or my control code is not correctly placed, but I've messed around with it and it stays the same.

Comment: cross-posted: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209504/dynamically-change-leaflet-layer

Comment: Try to create a jsFiddle if it's possible.

Comment: You might be interested in [LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) plugin. You can also check out other Leaflet [time related plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#time--elevation).